Armature doesn't work with my model
I created a model for my game. It's called "Player" in blender view port. I also created an armature for it with the name "metarig". When I combine "metarig" and "Player", selecting them through "Shift" and pressing "Ctrl+P", I choose option "With automatic weight". However when I try to move the bones in the "Pose Mode", they move, but the "Player" itself doesnt move and remains static. How can I solve this problem? My blender file to look at

Your mesh is too dense, that's the main problem, you could scale up the armature and object, apply the scale and rotation and parent again, but you'll still have some problems, the best is to create a low-poly version of your character.

Thank you, it worked!
